# XAML Page constructor

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a Silverlight 4 application.

What would cause the Constructor in my codebehind file to be called more than once?

Currently I suspect it gets called when I set the datacontext or do applytemplate.

I can see it when I debug the application and I put a breakpoint on the first line in my constructor, BUT it does not give me a stacktrace.

Thanks

Comment: In which file is it being called twice? App? MainPage? a nav Frame Usercontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the constructor should only be called once per control instance. Is your control maybe used more than once in your app? Or maybe a page that includes the control is instantiated more than once?

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the MainPage.xaml.cs file can have a {usercontroname}_Loaded event.

I moved my method call that started the database query to that event instead of the constructor.

Works like a charm now.